# Android (Galaxy Tab 6) Will not reboot to bootloader

Tags: rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat, odin, samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

Im hoping someone can point me in the right direction. So I am in the process of attempting to unlock the bootloader on my Galaxy Tab 6. However, the device will not boot to the bootloader. I can use the Vol up + Home + Power to get to the menu options (Wipe cache, Wipe data, Reboot to bootloader etc..). However, the reboot to bootloader option simply restarts the device to the OS. I have no issue booting to the OS at all.

First I thought I had a corrupt bootloader. I used ODIN to reflash the stock OS, CSC, and BL to the tablet using the Samsung provided files.  in BL I selected BL_T580XXU3BRF1_CL13839138_QB18630808_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5 . In AP I selected AP_T580XXU3BRF1_CL13839138_QB18630808_REV00_user_low_ship_meta.tar.md5 , I left CP blank as there was nothing provided, and lastly for CSC I chose CSC_OXX_T580OXX3BRF3_CL13878383_QB18711126_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5 . As far as ODIN options go, I have used Phone EFS clear, bootloader update, NAND erase all, and re-partition. I have had no success though. The tablet boots and works fine other than not being able to boot to the bootloader. Its really strange. Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Samsung devices don't have a fastboot mode in the first place.

Comment: If thats the case, how would you unlock the bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I discovered that its a problem that was quite common with the T580. I was mistaken about fastboot being on there. The issue is actually with the version of TWRP that was being used. It it for the T580, but does not work. This file must be used -- twrp_3.2.3-1_sm-t580_29918.tar . That version works flawlessly.